# Drawing a bar chart in the background of candlestick chart in apexchart

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, candlestick-chart

I am playing with candlestick graphs (example from here: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/candlestick-charts/basic/) everything work as expected.

However, I am struggling with adding my signal data for a visual representation of the graph.

I am unable to find a solution that works I was thinking I can somehow fine-tune a timeline - I tried chart.js/apexcharts and for now, I believe the closest will be with the second framework.

What I need is a bar chart that can be used in numeric ranges for the X and Y-axis as presented below. (the goal is to be able to add the green bar as presented)

Is there an easy win or an idea of how to approach this?
Is there something I am missing?

[image: chart I want to get]

Comment: The closest I got was with using the boxPlot - but it is far from optimal

Comment: The second approach is with type line - it is a bit better than boxPlot - still not the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: final version]

After weeks of playing around with it - the solution stayed:

1. I got two instances of apexcharts one with candlestick and one with line graphs
2. they are in a single div with CSS playground and position absolute.
3. I am passing standardised min/max values and has to have the same amount of elements in them (line graphs are allowing You to add null values which allow using this solution.

The final version work is repeatable and looks good.
if you need some help in similar case - feel free to reach out ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is my current solution (line graphs with stopWin/stopLose and entry price).

Still suboptimal - but works and is easy to achieve.

[image]